# moved ssl certificate from one apache server to another however site does not works with www

Tags: apache, openssl, ssl-certificate, virtualhost, ubuntu-10.04

I have recently moved my site from one VPS to another. Everything is done right and working fine except one problem of ssl.

My site uses ssl. (using rapidssl certificate)

I followed the instructions from here to move my certificates from one server to another.
http://www.sslshopper.com/apache-server-ssl-installation-instructions.html

The problem I am facing is very strange to me. In HTTPS mode, My site works fine with the like url http://stackoverflow.com, https://stackoverflow.com however it does not work with https://www.stackoverflow.com (notice www).

The problem is strange to me because it does work on old server.

Thanks in advance.
Pras

Here are my virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot/
ServerName stackoverflow.com
ServerAlias www.stackoverflow.com
<Directory //var/www/webroot/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost ***.***.***.***:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName stackoverflow.com
    ServerAlias www.stackoverflow.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot/
    <Directory /var/www/webroot/>
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/thirdparty.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/thirdparty.key
    SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/thirdpartyssl.ca
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Isn't *www.stackoverflow.com* a different server than *stackoverflow.com*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

First of all the problamatic url pattern was not working on the old server too. This has been confirmed by certificate guys.

So, I decide to forward all the "https://www.stackoverflow.com" url requests to https://stackoverflow.com. To do this, I have added few .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

These rules are generic and can work with all websites.

Hope this will save the time of others.